# c# How to Check if an Exception Was Already Thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I feel like I'm over thinking this or perhaps going the wrong way about it, but high level all I am trying to do is to catch errors that are thrown in my application, log them in the database, then redirect to a soft error page.

In my Global.asax, I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog(Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(), true);
            Response.Redirect("/error.aspx?id=" + error.ID);
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/error.aspx");
        }           
    }
```

Error log is a class I created that performs the record insertion and stuff like that.

Now the problem I am running into is that if there is something wonky with the database, like it being offline, an error in the stored procedure, etc, I get caught into an infinite loop of errors being inserted.

A solution I was trying to come up with this to resolve this behavior was to perhaps check if an error was already thrown, and if so, do not attempt to try a record insertion, but I haven't been able to find much on this.

Again, maybe I'm not going about this the correct way?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Perhaps the code that causes the database error will continue running despite an error being thrown?

Comment: Are you basically saying that your architecture is "we will catch no exceptions, everything will bubble up to app level" and the only place an error is ever handled is in this event?

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that.  This is last case scenario. I have a lot of other error handling in the application that catches errors and logs in.  This is for errors that are not handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually possible to do this, but I really don't think it's a good idea.

You can theoretically use [`Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptionpointers.aspx) to detect it. If it returns IntPtr.Zero, it probably means that there is no exception in flight; otherwise, it probably means that there is.

I say "probably" because the MSDN documentation for `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()` says under remarks:

> GetExceptionPointers is exposed for compiler support of structured exception handling (SEH) only.

So that sounds like a big fat *"don't use this"* to me.

With that proviso, this program will actually tell you whether an exception is in flight or not, without using a try/catch to do so:

**Warning: Nasty code ahead**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (new Test())
                {
                    // All is well.
                }

                using (new Test())
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Eeep");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception detected: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    sealed class Test: IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() == IntPtr.Zero
                ? "Disposing test normally."
                : "Disposing test because of an exception.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check if you are already on that page and redirect only if you are not as:

```
string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

if(!cTheFile.EndsWith("error.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    Response.Redirect("/error.aspx");
```

Comment: Well, it never gets to the redirect statement.  I have a db call being made inside the ErrorLog class, which if there's a problem there, then it bubbles up to Application_Error, tries to log it and the cycle begins.

Comment: @StanleyJenkins No the redirect will stop with this code... check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Override Exception class with ErrorLogDBInsertException and throw this one if something bad with DB stuff. Catch a specific Error

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ErrorLog.Log();
        Response.Redirect("/error.aspx?id=" + error.ID);
    }
    catch(ErrorLogDBInsertException err)
    {

        try 
        {
            // here you can log into event log
        }
        catch {}
        Response.Redirect("/SimpleNoDBCallPage_error.aspx");

    } 
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/PageThatCallsDB_error.aspx");
    }           
}
```